# Problem with bibliography. Double quotes appear around title

Tags: bibliographies, cite-package

```
    “Samsung’s “3D vertical” NAND crams a terabit on
    a single chip,” http://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2013/08/
    samsungs-3d-vertical-nand-crams-a-terabit-on-a-single-chip/.
```

This is how it appears in my bibliography. I am using cite and url packages.

My code looks like this

```
    \bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
    \bibliography{IEEEabrv,mybib}
```

My entry in bib file is

```
    @article{samsung_1TB_SSD2,
      title={Samsung's ``3{D} Vertical'' {NAND} crams a terabit on a single chip},
      note = {\url{http://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2013/08/samsungs-3d-vertical-nand-crams-a-terabit-on-a-single-chip/}}
            }
```

I do not want double quotes around title and it should maintain the case. I tried biblatex package but that does not work with IEETran. Please help

Comment: Is this for a journal submission? If so, this is perhaps what they require, so you shouldn't concern yourself with trying to fix/change it.

Comment: yes it is for scientific paper. But in their sample too I do not see quotes around title.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 4):

If the journal requires you to use the `IEEEtran` bibliography style, you shouldn't modify any of the style file's settings -- including the one that automatically places double quotes around the `title` field of an entry of type `@article`, in apparent contravention of the stated stylistic requirements...

What you *can* -- and probably should -- do for the sake of good typography is to use *single quotes* instead of double quotes to surround the string `3D Vertical`.

Second, to preserve the uppercase spelling of some of the letters in the `title` field, just surround them with curly braces. (You've already done just this with the string `NAND`, by the way.)

Thus, you may want to write the entry's title field as

```
title = {Samsung's `{3D Vertical}' {NAND} crams a terabit on a single chip},
```